# Design Timer circuit

Tags: timer

Hi Am looking for to design timer circuit for run Exhaust fan

My requirement is
three phase 1 HP motor, 440 V ac, 50 Hz supply
On time ; 4 Min
Off time: 1 min
so i need this cycle continuously. meant to say once the motor power on it has to run for 4 min and 1 min it has to stop then(4 ON + 1 OFF=5 min) 6 min it will run for another 4 min. so anyone kindly advise me how to design timer circuit for my Application.

Comment: Buy a cheap PLC and a contactor?

Answer (score 3):

As is evidenced in the comments, you should consider using an off-the-shelf solution such as a micro-PLC (programmable logic controller).

[image]

*Figure 3. A micro PLC with keypad and LCD.*

The small DIN-rail mounted types typically feature eight inputs and four outputs on the base module with expansion modules available to plug in or network connection. The one in the photo is from Crouzet but most of the big manufacturers - Allen-Bradley, Siemens, Mitsubishi, etc., have a version. You would require the AC-powered version with relay or triac output to power a contactor for your application.

For a very basic sequence as you describe they can be programmed from the front panel. For more complex jobs you will need the programming software.

Prices in Europe are typically somewhere around €100.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply. is any other option to make my own device. if you know the circuit diagram share to me i will design it here itself instead of simply buy.